# noSuchElementException on form submit

Tags: java, jsf, exception

We're using JSF 1.2 for our application. There is a selectBooleanCheckbox on on of the screens that represents a field in the backing bean. When loading the JSP, the value is shown correctly. There are three command buttons on the page; one calls a save function in the backing bean and then navigates to another screen. The other two are used to call utility methods in the backing bean before refreshing the screen. If the checkbox is unchecked, all three buttons function correctly. If the checkbox is checked, only the first functions as intended.

When the checkbox is selected, the backing bean is initialized but before the methods are called, a noSuchElementException is thrown from the generated servlet. The exception has a null message and no stack trace, so it's not incredibly helpful.

I've verified that the values of each field remain consistent with those that the screen is originally populated with. Dropdown inconsistencies are the only times I've ever seen this before, so any pointers on what else to check would be greatly appreciated. Unfortunately, I'm unable to post the code here but I will answer any questions if I am able.

Comment: How different the second/third button from the first one? Can you make them submit the form?

Comment: They are all of type 'submit.' The only difference is that the first button navigates back to the previous screen, while the other two make their modifications and refresh the current screen. They're all nearly identical - each uses the hx:commandExButton tag and the action points to a method in the backing bean. I'm not seeing anything in the functionality of the buttons that should make them behave differently.

Comment: Havent touched 1.2 for years , can you set them do some redirect tothat same page ?

Comment: Actually, I think I just found my issue - the save button is calling a javascript function that toggles the enabled/disabled property of one of the variables. Adding that to the other two seems to have fixed it... I have no idea why, but I have a starting point now. Could you move your comment to a question so I can give you rep for helping me to notice that?

Comment: Ahhh... I see what it's doing now. There was a dropdown indicating a property of the entity we're working on; that dropdown is disabled if the checkbox is selected (the checkbox essentially says that this is the primary entity of a group of such entities, so it has a bit more protection around it), and without enabling the dropdown, it's comparing a list of types with... nothing, because the dropdown doesn't exist, as far as it's concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at your buttons , and how is the working one being different from the non working ones.